# Multiple phantom Hard Drives

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I've got a weird problem with 20.04 server. The system had a drive failure and I had to rebuild it. Everything went fine during the install, but when I run **lsblk**, I show **sda - sdf**. There are only 2 SATA drives on this system, a 4tb drive for storage and a 240gb primary drive. I can't seem to get the phantom drives to go away and it driving my OCD nuts evey time I look at it. Anyone know how to resolve it and save my sanity?

Comment: Please include the output of `lsblk` in your question so that we can see what you see.

Comment: Here's what's showing up. 
I tried to format this, but when I try to add a new line, it submits my entry. The following is a cut and paste from the terminal.
`sda      8:0    1     0B  0 disk
sdb      8:16   1     0B  0 disk 
sdc      8:32   1     0B  0 disk 
sdd      8:48   1     0B  0 disk 
sde      8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sde1   8:65   0   1.8T  0 part /share/movies
sdf      8:80   0 232.8G  0 disk 
├─sdf1   8:81   0     1M  0 part 
└─sdf2   8:82   0 232.8G  0 part /`